Amplitude error of STFT using gaussian window
I am implementing the STFT algorithm and I also need to find the amplitude accuracy and Probability of Intercept (POI).
The only reference I have been given for these factors is this formula
$$ E_{ZD,S_{p}, dB} \left( \frac{fsbb}{BZF} \right) = 5.79 \frac{1}{ \left( \frac{fsbb}{BZF}\right)^2} dB \tag{1} \label{1}$$
Maybe more information, I have to use the Gaussian window for this STFT implementation. Also its written $\frac{fsbb}{BZF} > 2$
Please help, I have no idea what is $fsbb$ or $BZF$ and the material is in a completely different language and not very helpful.
Thank you in advance.

Hello and welcome to Signal Processing SE. I think that if you really want to implement or find out more about STFT you should consult a textbook that is either in your language or, at least in one that you understand. By the way, I tried to convert your equation to MathJax but I am not sure I did that correctly; could you please have a look and let me know if something is wrong (or correct it yourself if you want)?

Hello, thank you for your help! However I have to follow this material and I need to implement this particular formula for calculating amplitude error of STFT. I have implemented the basic STFT algorithm and I think I have a basic enough knowledge of same but this is stumping me.

Since you have the material, I believe that you could possible share some more information from it to generate some context. All those acronyms mean nothing to (and possibly to other people too) and it’s not easy to help when we don’t know what we are looking at (how can you help on something you cannot comprehend?).
